# Apache Cocoon 2.2 : Publish XML files in PDF is not working for greek language

Tags: xml, apache, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-cocoon

I'm working on a Apache Cocoon Project and I want to publish XML documents in PDF. I used the following pipeline:

```
 <map:pipeline id="pdf">
      <map:match pattern="pd/*/*/data.pdf">
        <map:generate src="PD{1}{2}.xml" type="file"/>
        <map:transform src="doc2pdf.xslt" type="xslt"/>
        <map:serialize type="fo2pdf"/>
      </map:match>
    </map:pipeline>
```

The .xslt is this one [here](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/1290_1_1.html) copied from Apache Cocoon How-Tos. My XML files contain Greek characters. A sample is [here](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~std07122/PD201210.xml).

The output of this transformation is like that:

```
http://localhost:8888/GRLegislation/pd/2011/54 ####### ####### ######### ##µ#####
##### #######µµ###### ########## ### ######## ### ####µ## ##### ### ###
########µ## ### (#### #####) text text/xml gr 2011-05-20 ###### A' 135 2011 ##
(######### ########) 54 2011 ######## ######### true ########## ######µ####
########## ##### true ########## ######µ###, ################## &#########
####### ########## true ########## #####µ##, ######### & ####### #######
######### true ######## ### ##µ######## ########## ### ####### ##### ########
#####
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching all day, I found that Apache Cocoon uses Apache FOP 1.0 . There is also a recent version of FOP 1.1. with Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency has broken links to some other dependencies, which FOP needs like Avalon framework 4.2 . I read somewhere that maybe this code can fix the issue:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <!-- these two are to correct issues in fop dependency --> 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
   <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
   <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Now compilation returns the following error: "Failed to execute goal org.apache.cocoon:cocoon-maven-plugin:1.0.0-M2:prepare (prepare) on project GRLegislation: There are at least two artifacts with the ID 'avalon-framework-api':
avalon-framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.2.0:compile".